# Error: ENOTDIR error each time I try to add a package to meteorjs

Tags: meteor

Each time I try on my Windows10 MeteorJS app to add a new package, e.g. through the command:
`meteor add iron:router` (same for other packages)

I'm getting following error:

```
C:\Users\Alek Kowalczyk\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.
windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: ENOTDIR, readdir 'C:\a7projects\a7\mymeteor-app\.meteor\.packages.1czbg
0o'
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\Alek Kowalczyk\AppData\Local\.meteor\package
s\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\fut
ure.js:398:15)
    at C:\tools\fs\files.js:1331:28
```

I tried:

- `meteor reset`
- delete the `local` folder in `.meteor`
- `npm clear cache`
- create a new app and test if it works - yup, problem is only on my already pretty developed.

I use `meteorhacks:npm` and `browserify` but dunno if that changes anything.

nothing helps, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by:

- Delete the `packages` folder created by the `meteorhacks:npm` package
- Remove the `npm-container` row in the `.meteor\packages` file

And it works. I hate solving issues that way - without knowing what the real reason was, but at least I can move on...

Answer (score 0):

its because the file is **read only**.

Easy, just go to the directory, right click on the corresponding file and uncheck it as read-only.